# opengl viewport in Mac with FMX delphi

Tags: macos, delphi, opengl, firemonkey

I have designed an application in Delphi FMX that uses a new component based on class TPresentedControl. This component presents the output of opengl functions. (something like drawing in a viewport with opengl). 
In Windows application runs successfully, but in MacOS it runs without this opengl viewport.
You can see a relative discussion here: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248299

Do I have to use NSOpenGLView instead of my component? 
If not what other options do i have?

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is interested, 
in GitHub (https://github.com/tothpaul/Firemonkey/tree/master/GLPanel) a developer named Friedrich Westermann
opened a new pull request for Pauls Toth' code in which he wrote a new part with code for Mac and also some changes to the existed. 
I have tested it and works perfectly on Mac.

Comment: Yes, but perfectly is not really true, it works for the example from Paul, but needs some work for a more generic way. As Example the Setup for the Modell and View Matrices should be exposed also to the GlPanel.